# Нужна ли в этом предложении еще одна запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Водитель грузовика подвез меня до города Джордж, высадив за пять километров до центра.

Comment: До города и до центра? Водитель грузовика подвез меня до города, высадив в пяти километрах от центра.

Answer (score 1):

**Водитель грузовика подвез меня до города Джордж, высадив за пять километров до центра.**

Подвез — что сделав? — высадив.
*Высадив за пять километров до центра* — деепричастный оборот (деепричастие + зависимые слова), перед ним ставится запятая.
Других мест для постановки запятой я не усматриваю.
[**Деепричастный оборот**](https://5-ege.ru/sintaksicheskie-normy/)

*В 12 часов, когда Петя был в **а** км от лагеря, его нагнал велосипедист и подвёз, высадив в **а** км от города* (из условия задачи).

*Там не сразу, но остановил частника, который меня немного подвёз, высадив через шесть кварталов* (В. Поселягин. Берсерк).

Comment: "Word" пишет: возможно, в конце деепричастного оборота пропущена запятая на отрезке предложения между словом "высадив" и словом "пять".

Comment: Если поставить запятую после "высадив", то это уже будет не деепричастный оборот, а одиночное деепричастие. Основное действие: подвез - куда? - до города; дополнительное: высадив - где? - за пять километров.

Comment: @Виктор Можно заменить деепричастие на глагол (если сомнения все же остаются), тогда границы оборота будут четко видны. _Водитель грузовика подвез меня до города Джордж и **высадил за пять километров до центра._**

Comment: Программа ошибается?

Comment: Вполне возможно, программа посчитала, что "до города" и "до центра" - это однородные члены.